# Generating XML file from WSDL

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui

I have a wsdl file with me and want to generate a sample XML file for request/response of an API. Using soapUI I managed to generate the file but it has question marks inside, like this: `<cin:returnURL>?</cin:returnURL>`. What I want is like this; `<cin:returnURL>---returnURL---</cin:returnURL>`.

Is there any way to to do this using soapUI or any other tool? I should also have the nested tag names if there any. E.g.:

```
        `<inq:Voice>
           <cin:description>---VoiceDescription---</cin:description>               
           <cin:EffectiveDates>
              <cin:effectiveDate>---VoiceEffectiveDate---</cin:effectiveDate>
           </cin:EffectiveDates>
        </inq:Voice>`
```

Comment: Use SoapUI:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752789/generating-xml-file-from-wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a tool which does exactly what you want with the WSDL. But if you don't like the question marks that soapUI uses as the default placeholder, you can go to the program's preferences and from there switch on the option WSDL Settings - Generate example values in new request. This way, the placeholders are replaced with random data.

Answer (score 0):

The ? are just placeholders. Replace with actual data.